# Regex how to skip empty values in php

Tags: php, regex

I'm doing a small program for generating random 4-letters passwords.
What I've already achieved is every time I refresh the page, it gives me exactly 4-letters password with exactly uppercase and lowercase letters, and integers using Regex.

The problem I'm trying to solve now is it sometime doesn't give a thing...Ok

I'm asking for solution to how to skip empty values..

```
$str="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
$pass=array();
$length=strlen($str)-1;
for($i=0;$i<4;$i++){
    $index=rand(0,$length);
    $pass[]=$str[$index];
}
$nPass=implode($pass);
echo "Password could be: ";

foreach($pass as $val){
    if(preg_match("/[a-z]/",$nPass)&&preg_match("/[A-Z]/",$nPass)&&preg_match("/[0-9]/",$nPass)){
        echo $val;
    }elseif(empty($nPass)){
        echo "NOT FOUND";
    }
    //echo "null";
}
```

Please suggest a solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do:

```
function gener_pass() {
    $lower = str_shuffle('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
    $upper = str_shuffle('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');
    $digit = str_shuffle('0123456789');
    $all = str_shuffle($lower . $upper . $digit);

    return str_shuffle($lower[0] . $upper[0] . $digit[0] . $all[0]);
}

for($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
    echo gener_pass(),"\n";
}
```

**output:**

```
T8tj
cME4
N5o7
zB24
n3VC
zYE7
b5WK
oRY2
uX5A
PDc8
```

Comment: Yeah  this is another way. I've never thought of using str_shuffle() function..Thanks

Comment: Oh just one part I didn'tunderstand return str_shuffle($lower[0] . $upper[0] . $digit[0] . $all[0]     in this return statement, are those the concatenation dots? we can use it in functions?

Comment: @KiraNofans: Yes, they are conatenation and yes, you can use it in function.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will work fine:

```
$password= generatePassword();
while(!preg_match("/[a-z]/", $password) || !preg_match("/[A-Z]/", $password) || !preg_match("/[0-9]/", $password))
{
    $password= generatePassword();
}
echo $password;
function generatePassword()
{
    $str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    $pass = array();
    $length = strlen($str) - 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)
    {
        $index = rand(0, $length);
        $pass[] = $str[$index];
    }
    $nPass = implode($pass);
    return $nPass;
}
```